# Scoreboard data transfer Serial Port c#

Tags: c#

There's some outdated software that's used to control the scoreboard at my local athletics track and I've been tasked with creating a new advanced one. However, I cannot seem to get the scoreboard to do what I ask it to do.

I've installed the original software to the my laptop and it works fine, however, when I run my test software that sends data to the board through the serial port, it isn't doing what I want.

I have the "Scoreboard Data Protocol" supplied by the manufacturer and I've been following this. I will supply the code to my test program that I've been using to see if I can get it to work and I will also supply the Data Protocol.

In the text box, I type `010D0201SPAIN` and `003C630` and send it to the board and this doesn't work.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private SerialPort m_port;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            m_list.Items.AddRange(SerialPort.GetPortNames()); // Adds ports to combobox

            m_port = new SerialPort();
            m_port.BaudRate = 9600;
            m_port.DataBits = 8;
            m_port.Parity = Parity.Even;
            m_port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            //m_port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            m_port.Encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

            m_port.RtsEnable = true;
            m_port.DtrEnable = true;

            m_port.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
            m_port.DataReceived += DataReceivedEvent;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_port.Close();
            m_port.PortName = (string)m_list.SelectedItem;

            try
            {
                m_port.Open();
                m_sendbutton.Enabled = true;
                button2.Enabled = true;
            }catch(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void m_sendbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_port.Write(m_textbox.Text);
        }
        private void DataReceivedEvent(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            Invoke(new EventHandler(DoUpdate));
        }

        private void DoUpdate(object s, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text += m_port.ReadLine();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] r_bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(m_textbox.Text);
            m_port.Write(r_bytes, 0, r_bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

[Scoreboard Data Protocol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPuXj.png)

Code: https://hastebin.com/epirobuduv.cs

Comment: " it isn't doing what I want." - can you explain what happens, and what you would like it to do instead?

Comment: Okay so at the moment, it does nothing when I send info from the program above, however when I send messages from the old software from 2004, it works fine. So there is something wrong with my code. I send `010D0201SPAIN     ` and `003C630` through my program and that should display the word SPAIN (as the data protocol says) but it doesn't happen.

Comment: You made no attempt whatsoever to implement the protocol.  Impossible to guess what the problem might be, you need to ask a *specific* question about it.

Comment: @HansPassant In the text box, I enter `010D0201SPAIN     ` and `003C630 ` and the scoreboard doesn't do what it says in the protocol

Comment: That was obvious, but that is not what the protocol says you need to do.  Read up about [the control codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character#In_ASCII) that indicate the start and end of a message.  Use Read and Write instead of Read/WriteLine().

Comment: @HansPassant I've read up about these before and I am a bit confused. I set up a virtual serial port and set up putty to monitor it. When I sent a message through the port from the old working software, it just said `010D...(MESSAGE)003C630`.

Also, about WriteLine, I've made a new test program and I've used:
https://pastebin.com/VnDb2rtj

Comment: '010D...(MESSAGE)003C630' is ASCII, but a serial link is really just bytes. e.g. the first '0' is actually sent as decimal 48 or 0x30 in hex (or whatever in binary). STX and ETX are bytes that are not printable in ASCII; you need to add them to your byte array before calling port.write

Comment: @RobinBennett Thanks for the help! There's one thing though. msg.Length is calling an error
https://imgur.com/a/lG6bdCo


EDIT: Nevermind, fixed. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to add STX and ETX around your message, in a byte array.

```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(m_textbox.Text).ToList();
        msg.Insert(0, 0x02); // STX at the start
        msg.Add(0x03); // ETX at the end
        m_port.Write(msg.ToArray(), 0, msg.Count);
    }
```

Comment: @Jack B - Would 'msg.Count' work? That would be neater.